# How to show a dynamical system is smooth or not smooth?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a a smooth dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^n$ :  $$\begin{align}
\phi:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}$$ where $\phi$ is a smooth function satisfies

1. $\phi_{0}(X)=X$
2. $\phi_{t} \circ \phi_{s}=\phi_{t+s}$  for $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$

Consider the following 3:

1. Time Dilation: $$\begin{align}
   \psi(t,X) :=\phi(at,X)
   \end{align}$$ where $a>0$
2. Time Reversal $$\begin{align}
   \psi(t,X):=\phi(-t,X)
   \end{align}$$
3. Time Translation $$\begin{align}
   \psi(t,X) := \phi(t-t_{0},X)
   \end{align}$$
   where $\phi_{-t_{0}}$ is not the identity function.

I'm asked to show that the first 2 are still smooth dynamical systems, but the third one is not. Then, if $\phi_{-t_{0}}$ is an identity function, can the third one become a smooth dynamical system?

I don't know where to start. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of a smooth dynamical system?

Comment: I think the definition of a smooth dynamical system is presented in 1 and 2. I think you mean that I can try to check whether the defined $\psi$ is satisfying these 2 requirements so that I can know whether it is a smooth dynamical system. For example, Time Translation, since the problem states that $\phi_{-t_0}$ is not an identity function. Thus, $\psi(0, X) \ne X$, so it is not a smooth dynamical system. Is this right?